# There is something about us that we see in that?

Tags: meaning, grammar

> I think Egypt has such a grip on us because they had access to stone …
>   and with that stone they built the world's first skyscrapers..**there's
>   something about us that we see in that.**

What does the last sentence mean?

Comment: *something about us* = *some [ill-defined] quality / attribute* that we have. In this context, apparently, a "timeless proclivity" for humans to erect tall edifices, so when we see the pyramids built by ancient Egyptians it reminds us that we're "the same" because we build modern skyscrapers.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning that makes most sense to me is that "us" refers to all humans, and that in all humans there is a need for permanence, which can be seen in stone, pyramids and skyscrapers.

Answer (score 0):

**something about someone or something**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/about) idiom

> something alluring or curious about someone or something.

As in:

> ..there's something about us that is insightful and alluring when we
>   look upon Egypt's 'skyscrapers'!